# C++ "Program.exe has stopped working"

Tags: c++

In no way I can solve why I'm getting the error in the screenshot when entering the first value and trying to proceed.

The error happens only with code below.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x08mS.png)

```
//Darbas40
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

int n,
    u,
    m,
    ms,
    v,
    vs,
    i;
double vidvaikinu,
       vidmerginu;

n = 7; m = 0; v = 0; ms = 0; vs = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    wcout << "Iveskite mokiniu ugius: "; cin >> u;
    if (u > 0)
    {
        m++;
        ms = ms + u;
    }
    else if (u < 0)
    {
        v++;
        vs = vs + u;
    }
    vidmerginu = ms / m;
    vidvaikinu = fabs(vs / v);
    }

   wcout << " " << endl;
   wcout << "vidvaikinu = " << vidvaikinu << ", vidmerginu = " << vidmerginu << "." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `v` is causing a divide by zero. That is why you should declare and initialize *one variable per line*, besides the fact that your code is very difficult to read as written due to the formatting and poor style.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: It's not your problem, but `vidmerginu = ms / m;` will do an integer division, and then convert the result to double.  You need something like `vidmerginu = double(ms) / m;`.  Same problem with vs/v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a divide by zero error if `u <= 0` in:

```
vidmerginu = ms / m;
```

because `m` is set to `0` and not incremented.

And a divide by zero error if `u >= 0` in:

```
vidvaikinu = fabs(vs / v);
```

because `v` is set to `0` and not incremented.